# Codeigniter ajax database lookup working on test site but not on production

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have followed a [tutorial](http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_17/Check_the_user_name_availability_with___Codeigniter_jQuery) on an ajax lookup that informs the user if the username is already taken. I have also done the tutorial in a localhost folder named login as per example. I have downloaded all their code and applied it. this works correctly on `localhost/login`

if I move the code across to my actual web application, `localhost/production` and adjust the syntax in the check.js file from:

```
url : baseurl + 'index.php/login/getResultfromdb/' + name,
```

to:

```
url : baseurl + 'getResultfromdb/' + name,
```

All other code remains the same as below.

My problem is that when the I enter data into the input field and the jquery / ajax is initiated, the result is always negative. red cross is shown as per the tutorial css. if I enter a username that is already taken it returns that it is available.

Now I have looked for errors in my google developer tools(F12) and cant see any. the only one that did appear was the url in check.js which I corrected as above.

My feeling is that the input value is not being fetched correctly by jquery so the database query is for a different value than the one entered.

Could this be an issue with the config of my codeigniter? an autoload or the like? I have checked all of what I know and it appears to be correct but values are still being returned incorrectly.

any advice is appreciated.

The controller syntax is:

```
<?php
    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {
        function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('loginView');
        }
        function getResultfromdb($username){

        $this->db->where('username',urldecode($username));
        $query = $this->db->get('users')->num_rows();
        if($query == 0 ) echo 'userOk';
        else echo 'userNo';
    }
    }
```

the view is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check User Name</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">

            <label for="username">Enter Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="username"/>
            <span class="checkUser" ></span>
            <input type="hidden" class="hiddenUrl"/>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/check.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

the check.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#username').blur(function(){

        if( $('#username').val().length >= 3 )
            {
              var username = $('#username').val();
              getResult(username); 
            }
        return false;
    })
    function getResult(name){
        var baseurl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
        $('.checkUser').addClass('preloader');
        $.ajax({
            url : baseurl + 'getResultfromdb/' + name,
            cache : false,
            success : function(response){
                $('.checkUser').removeClass('preloader');
                if(response == 'userOk') $('.checkUser').removeClass('userNo').addClass('userOk');
                else $('.checkUser').removeClass('userOk').addClass('userNo');;
            }
        })
    }
})
```

As mentioned, this works great on my localhost/login but not on my localhost/production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is incorrect.Try this

```
url : baseurl + 'index.php/getResultfromdb/' + name,
```

Comment: Hi, my htacccess removes the index.php from the url? this creates an error with 'failed to load resource'. any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its the .htaccess in your production server. you need to put the one that is in your localhost.

also try to browser the url directly from browser and see if you can access it.

Also check if you have enable csrf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Thanks, my htaccess on my login test is default `deny from all`. the htaccess on my server has been set to remove the index string from url. `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /production/

How can I fix it? Thanks,
# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: and the csrf settings in both config files is set to `FALSE`. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: any ideas on what the issue can be? given my htaccess on the server? please advise. Thanks again

Comment: just copy the .htaccess from localhost and put it on the production server. did you make some changes to .htaccess on your production server that you needed? if yes make those changes in your local .htaccess and upload it. you can find a default .htaccess in codeigniter website that you can use. if you developed the entire site your self then its ok, but if you didnt you dont want to mess with .htaccess

Comment: my htaccess just needs to remove the idex.php from the url, no other functionality.

Comment: remove everything from .htaccess and put the following code to remove index.php     RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Thanks, moved the htaccess from my server to my localhost and it worked still so don't think this is an htaccess issue. any other ideas?

Comment: did you restart apache after moving htaccess?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25457/discussion-between-smudger-and-muhammad-nasir)